# IONIC. Error en ionic.The target entry-point "@ionic-native/geolocation" has missing dependencies: [ng] - @ionic-native/core

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

Marzo del 2021, Instalo Ionic 6, creo un proyecto con la plantilla blank y con "capacitor". Lo ejecuto y todo bien. Ahora instalo la dependencia de Geolocalizacion de la siguiente manera como indica en la documentacion de ionic:

```
npm install cordova-plugin-geolocation
npm install @ionic-native/geolocation
ionic cap sync
```

Ejecuto y no da ningún error tampoco.
Ahora en el fichero home.page.ts, importo la dependencia de geolocalizacion de la siguiente manera:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(){}

}
```

Ejecuto el proyecto y me salta el siguiente error:

```
[ng] An unhandled exception occurred: The target entry-point "@ionic-native/geolocation" has missing dependencies:
[ng]  - @ionic-native/core
```

En el log del error me dice lo siguiente:

```
[error] Error: The target entry-point "@ionic-native/geolocation" has missing dependencies:
 - @ionic-native/core

    at TargetedEntryPointFinder.findEntryPoints (C:\Users\JAVIERT\Desktop\Proyectos\Ionic\myAppGpsM1\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\entry_point_finder\targeted_entry_point_finder.js:40:23)
    at C:\Users\JAVIERT\Desktop\Proyectos\Ionic\myAppGpsM1\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\analyze_entry_points.js:29:41
    at SingleProcessExecutorSync.SingleProcessorExecutorBase.doExecute (C:\Users\JAVIERT\Desktop\Proyectos\Ionic\myAppGpsM1\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\single_process_executor.js:28:29)
    at C:\Users\JAVIERT\Desktop\Proyectos\Ionic\myAppGpsM1\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\single_process_executor.js:57:59
    at SyncLocker.lock (C:\Users\JAVIERT\Desktop\Proyectos\Ionic\myAppGpsM1\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\locking\sync_locker.js:34:24)
    at SingleProcessExecutorSync.execute (C:\Users\JAVIERT\Desktop\Proyectos\Ionic\myAppGpsM1\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\single_process_executor.js:57:27)
    at Object.mainNgcc (C:\Users\JAVIERT\Desktop\Proyectos\Ionic\myAppGpsM1\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\main.js:74:25)
    at Object.process (C:\Users\JAVIERT\Desktop\Proyectos\Ionic\myAppGpsM1\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\index.js:29:23)
    at NgccProcessor.processModule (C:\Users\JAVIERT\Desktop\Proyectos\Ionic\myAppGpsM1\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngcc_processor.js:163:16)
    at C:\Users\JAVIERT\Desktop\Proyectos\Ionic\myAppGpsM1\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\host.js:55:18
    at C:\Users\JAVIERT\Desktop\Proyectos\Ionic\myAppGpsM1\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\host.js:47:24
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.host.resolveModuleNames (C:\Users\JAVIERT\Desktop\Proyectos\Ionic\myAppGpsM1\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\host.js:45:32)
    at actualResolveModuleNamesWorker (C:\Users\JAVIERT\Desktop\Proyectos\Ionic\myAppGpsM1\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:102904:133)
    at resolveModuleNamesWorker (C:\Users\JAVIERT\Desktop\Proyectos\Ionic\myAppGpsM1\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:103126:26)
    at resolveModuleNamesReusingOldState (C:\Users\JAVIERT\Desktop\Proyectos\Ionic\myAppGpsM1\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:103200:24)
```

Cómo soluciono el problema?

Comment: Ya está resuelto, instalé el componente nativo @ionic-native/core.